# Result java choice solution

Tags: java, android, arrays

Sorry, if I ask, can anyone help my Android project if the quiz formula results like this ... ??

1. if the dominant answer is A then the result is A
2. if the dominant answer is B then the result is B
3. if the dominant answer is C then the result is C
4. if the dominant answer is D then the result is D
5. if A is equal to B, C, D then the result is E

   - the choice of using imagebutton and 6 questions
   - the result I have typed in string.xml what is the code so that each result declaration is called ... ??

please help me

----under this my code, how do the statements for the formula above:-----

```
public class mquiz extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button btn_next;

ImageButton jawabA, jawabB, jawabC, jawabD;

TextView question;

String [] kuisioner ={"Your hobbies..??","Which object do you like...??"};

//Pilihan Gambar
int [] pilihA ={R.drawable.seeing, R.drawable.picture};
int [] pilihB ={R.drawable.singing, R.drawable.songer};
int [] pilihC ={R.drawable.readwrite, R.drawable.writestory};
int [] pilihD ={R.drawable.activity, R.drawable.football};
private int indeks;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_quiz);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_quiz1);

    question=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
    question.setText(kuisioner[0]);

    jawabA=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pilihanA);
    jawabA.setImageResource(pilihA[0]);
    jawabA.setOnClickListener(this);

    jawabB=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pilihanB);
    jawabB.setImageResource(pilihB[0]);
    jawabB.setOnClickListener(this);

    jawabC=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pilihanC);
    jawabC.setImageResource(pilihC[0]);
    jawabC.setOnClickListener(this);

    jawabD=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pilihanD);
    jawabD.setImageResource(pilihD[0]);
    jawabD.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view){

    indeks++;
    if (view == jawabA){
        jawabA.setImageResource(pilihA[indeks]);
    }
    if (view == jawabB){
        jawabB.setImageResource(pilihB[indeks]);
    }
    if (view == jawabC){
        jawabC.setImageResource(pilihC[indeks]);
    }
    if (view == jawabD){
        jawabD.setImageResource(pilihD[indeks]);
    }
    if (view == btn_next){
        Intent start = new Intent(mquiz.this, samplequiz.class);
        startActivity(start);
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend reading up on the equals method, instead of running all your comparisons with referential comparisons. also: add else-keywords where applicable, it'll make your code a tad more efficiënt

Comment: retrieve the results in string.xml, how do I ... ??
what is typed in java.class or xml. can give the sample code for my problem...?? 
I can later learn specific.

Comment: you are making mistakes against the basics which have a big impact on your code, and you don't seem to be aware of naming conventions, yet you are trying to write (more) advanced code. don't. learn the basics first

Comment: I want to make a multiple personality quiz test and later the result is text taken in string.xml.